# How to print matched and not matched based on matched condtion using angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5705f793e4b0acd6e2456804a"
    },
    "Categories": [
        {
            "mainmodels": [
                {
                    "submodels": [
                        {
                            "price": "2000",
                            "submodelname": "lumia021",
                            "Remainingphones": "2",
                            "Bookedphones": "8",
                            "Numofphones": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "price": "4000",
                            "submodelname": "lumia K6",
                            "Remainingphones": "0",
                            "Bookedphones": "15",
                            "Numofphones": "15"
                        }

                    ],
                    "Status": "Active",
                    "modelname": "lumia",
                    "fromdate": "2016-04-01T16:39:12.051Z",
                    "todate": "2016-04-31T19:19:44.051Z"
                }
            ],
            "brand": "nokia"
        }
    ],
    "rank": "1",
    "name": "kalasipalaya"
}
```

I have given my object above i need to check every submodel(here two sumodels is there)Numofphones and Bookedphones are matched . if both(here i given two submodel) Numofphones and Bookedphones are matched i need to print matched otherwise i need to print not matched how can i solve this one help me out .

Comment: is this array of object?

Comment: yeah i have given my object

Comment: is there single object or multiple object?

Comment: single object and submodels is multiple

Comment: @komal have edited the answer please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   //This will take to submodel array of object

    var _getSubModel = m[0].Categories[0].mainmodels[0].submodels;
    var _newArray2 = []; 

    //Checking if Bookedphones of first object submodel, is same with other objects.

    var _newArray = _getSubModel.filter(function(item){
       return item.Bookedphones == _getSubModel[0].Bookedphones;
    })
    // If all the Bookedphones are same then length of _newArray & submodel will be same.
   // If same then check for Numofphones

    if(_getSubModel.length == _newArray.length){
     _newArray2 =  _getSubModel.filter(function(item){
       return item.Numofphones == _getSubModel[0].Numofphones;
    })
    // If all Numofphones are same,then length of _newArray2 & submodel will be same
    if(_getSubModel.length == _newArray2.length){
    console.log('Matched');
    }
     else{
     console.log('Not Matched');
     }
    }
    else{
    console.log('Not Matched');
    }
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/hem4p326/2/)

Comment: not like this i need to show only matched or not matched .if two object values are matched i need to show matched otherwise i need to show not matched

Comment: do you mean to say if all objects of submodel has same Bookedphones or Numofphones  then it will be matched else unmatched?

Comment: yeah i want like that

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) something like that:

```
        var result = [];
        angular.forEach(submodels, function (submodel) {
            if(submodel.Numofphones == submodel.Bookedphones)
                result.push(submodel);
        });
        return result;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y7r1xe0t/236/

**UPDATED:** http://jsfiddle.net/y7r1xe0t/237/

```
return function (submodels, matched_or_not) {
        var result = [];
        angular.forEach(submodels, function (submodel) {
            if(matched_or_not && submodel.Numofphones == submodel.Bookedphones)
                result.push(submodel);
            else if(!matched_or_not && submodel.Numofphones != submodel.Bookedphones)
                result.push(submodel);
        });
        return result;
};
```

Filter will return matched object when you send `true`.

[image]

Comment: check jsfiddle. there are two objects on console. your result is inside second object.

Comment: i could not understand ..this s not my expectation